# Xamarin Camera2Basic write device watermark on photo

Tags: xamarin, android-camera2

I'm using Xamarin camera2basic.

When I taking photos on some picture write a text device watermark "**SHOT ON MI A2**" and some picture without that.
I want to take photo without watermark.
How can I disable watermark.

**On my device camera setting I disabled watermark but in my App it's enable for some picture.**

[here is 2 pictures by my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsAne.jpg)

Comment: This is the system default setting on MI device . And you could close it manually . Check Leon's answer here .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/320152/xamarin-camera2basic-write-device-watermark-on-pho.html

Comment: I said **On my device camera setting I disabled watermark but in my App it's enable for some picture.** 

I disabled both of  "Time Watermark" and "Dual Camera Watermark" . but in my app write "Dual Camera Watermark" on some photo.